# GameServer with python(Tornado 6 + pyMySQL) SQL Connection failed 255

Tags: python, tornado, pymysql

Im trying bring to live this [code](https://github.com/VAPus/PyOT)
I fixed few things but im stuck on connect to mysql.
Game server use python 3.4 and old tornado 4.
I want rebuild code for newest pytohn and tornado.
I was installed newest stable python and created venv.
In venv i have newest Tornado and PyMySQL.

> SQL Connection to localhost failed, trying 127.0.0.1
> SQL Connection with localhost failed, trying 127.0.0.1
> SQL Connection failed TCPClient.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'io_loop' check SQL settings in config.py!

I was remove from conncection.py
in

```
 def __init__(self, host="localhost", user=None, passwd="",
             database=None, port=3306, unix_socket=None,
             charset='', sql_mode=None,
             read_default_file=None, conv=decoders, use_unicode=None,
             client_flag=0, cursorclass=Cursor, init_command=None,
             connect_timeout=None, ssl=None, read_default_group=None,
             compress=None, named_pipe=None, no_delay=False,
             autocommit=False, db=None, io_loop=None):
```

i removed io_loop=None

next, i removed

```
self.io_loop = io_loop or tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
```

and fixed from this

```
    @coroutine
    def connect(self):
        client = TCPClient(io_loop=self.io_loop)
        self.stream = yield client.connect(self.host, self.port)
```

to this

```
@coroutine
def connect(self):
    client = TCPClient()
    self.stream = yield client.connect(self.host, self.port)
```

but i get errors

> Loading items...
>
> Items (17721) loaded...                                             [DONE]
>
> SQL Connection to localhost failed, trying 127.0.0.1 SQL Connection
> with localhost failed, trying 127.0.0.1 SQL Connection failed 255
> check SQL settings in config.py!

Im using newset WAMP Server for MySQL and in gameserver config i have

```
sqlModule = "mysql" # # Can be "mysql" or "tornado-mysql".
sqlUsername = "root"
sqlPassword = ""
sqlDatabase = "pyot" # Either a DB name, or file for sqlite3
sqlHost = "localhost"
```

How to connect to the mysql(SQL Connection failed 255)?